# How to output sklearn standardscaler

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have standardized my data in sklearn using preprocessing.standardscaler. Question is how could I save this in my local for latter use?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to save your trained model so it can be loaded again correct?

There are two methods, using python's `pickle` and the other method which is to use `joblib`. The recommend method is `joblib` as this will result in a much smaller file than a pickle, which dumps a string representation of your object:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl') 

#then load it later, remember to import joblib of course

clf = joblib.load('filename.pk1')
```

See the [online docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#model-persistence)

Note: `sklearn.externals.joblib` is deprecated. Install and use the pure `joblib` instead