# How to load a scikit-learn machine learning module in memory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I created a SVM classifier using scikit-learn; basically it  pulls in a description and then returns a category based upon that description.

Currently I have created an API using the [FLASK](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) framework in order to send my calls to a centralized Linux box. However I've been pickling and then unpickling it every time to use it, but I'd like to create a persistent loaded model in order to speed up my classification time.

1. Are there either resources people could recommend or
2. direct me on how to accomplish this?

Comment: The preferred method is to use joblib see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201339/how-to-output-sklearn-standardscaler/23203622#23203622 it's more compact than pickling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pickle

model = pickle.load(path)

def predict(val):
    return model.predict(val)
```

Declaring files outside a function keeps them in memory till the api is running.
Call predict function from your flask script.